# Best Interface for Reading XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

SimpleXML seems OK, but one thing that's annoying is whenever assigning/storing a value you have to typecast it - this really is a tad annoying. DOM is OK but I really like the flexibility of XPath, sometimes DOM can be a tad too much writing-wise.

I really like the selector implementation in jQuery, and the flexibility. I came across http://jquery.hohli.com/ while googling but just wanted to see if anyone had recommendations before I try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `SimpleXmlElement` for reading and `DOMDocument` for creating XML. You can also look at the [XMLReader](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) as in PHP 5.1. This is a fast way to "walktrough" an XML document. PHP also provides [event-based XML parsing](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) (SAX).

If you have a good combination of read/write actions you maybe should extend the `SimpleXmlElement` or `DOMDocument` classes or write a few helper functions which do all that casting work for you.

Comment: I was thinking about extending SimpleXMLElement - I think I'll go ahead with that.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/simplexml) - it does support XPath with [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-xpath.php).

Maybe a bit more information on what you're trying to do... are you reading a whole XML file into a data structure, or just trying to grab one or two values from it?

Comment: It varies - SimpleXML is nice when you're doing subtle things but sometimes I do have to modify the structure a bit and that's when I get frustrated by all the typecasting that's needed.